# Stochastic simulation in R with large matrices

Tags: stochastic-processes, simulation, queueing-theory

I am running a simulation in $R$ of a queueing system. One of the problems I have is that the running time is heavily impacted by a read operation on a matrix that has to be performed multiple times (at each event for my event based simulation). In this matrix I store the job/server compatibilities, however due to the nature of the model this matrix has a size of $\binom{N}{d} \times N$, where $d$ is fixed and I am especially interested in the model behaviour as $N$ grows large. As you can see this is a problem as the number of rows is $O(N^d)$. The matrix itself is very sparse, each row only contains $d$ entries $True$ and $N-d$ entries $False$ (it is a logical matrix).

One of the problems with this is that the running time of my simulation grows exponentially due to the read operation on this enormous matrix. I have tried various methods to speed it up, but I'm not sure where to continue. The matrix I have currently is a sparse matrix, created by first creating via

$Matrix(compatibilityMatrix,sparse=T).$

I know that casting a matrix to sparse is not very efficient, but this is just a one time operation at the start of the simulation and does not impact the running time. During the simulation I need to read random rows of this matrix, of which there are $\binom{N}{d}$. I have tried transposing the matrix and doing reads on the columns just in case the matrices are stored in column order, but to no avail. Does anyone know whether there is a faster method to read entries from such a matrix?

Comment: If it's just a logical matrix then it doesn't technically need to be a matrix at all, it can just be a hash structure containing the $d^2$ pairs that are true. Are you doing any actual linear algebra operations with this matrix?

Comment: No, the matrix is just to store the job/server compatibilities. So I just need to read from the matrix to determine which servers are active given the job types in the central queue. Each job is compatible with a unique subset of $d$ servers, so I have $\binom{N}{d}$ job types, hence the number of rows each containing only $d$ entries of $True$ and the rest $False$. I've never really heard of hash structures, so I'll look into that if it is a better way to store this.

Comment: It won't likely make much difference compared to a sparse structure because a sparse structure should really have something very similar to a hash map underlying it anyway, to tell the program which entries are 0. But yeah, the space requirements here at least should be no big deal unless $N$ is ludicrously huge (like too big to fit in a 64 bit signed int), since there are only $d^2$ nonzero entries.

Comment: No the matrix still fits into memory just fine for the values of $N$ I am simulating for. One problem is just that the reads from the matrix become more time intensive as $N$ grows (since the matrix explodes in size), furthermore to get a good approximation with my monte carlo simulation I need to simulate much longer the more servers I have in the model (otherwise the average arrivals per server is very low, thus not giving me a good approximation of the queue lengths of servers). The arrival rate also scales with the number of servers, hence the exponential growth of the running time.

Comment: An individual read task should not get any more intensive if there's only $d^2$ true's and you don't have to do anything with the false's. If that's the case then you need a different data structure.

Comment: Sorry, it's not $d^2$ I guess, it is more like $\frac{N^d}{(d-1)!}$. So that explains it. Sounds like your problem is just plain expensive. What are your runtimes like?

Comment: Just to give an example, I am simulating for $10^4*N$ arrivals for a good convergence (so every server has on average $10^4$ arrivals). For $N=1000$ one iteration already takes about an hour, while it only takes about 2 minutes for $N=20$. This is in part because the number of arrivals I want scales with $N$, but the central queue length also scales with $N$ and also with the load of the queueing system. The larger the central queue length, the more reads it needs to do from the matrix.

Comment: A problem with the model is I am looking into redundancy in queueing, the same job is routed to multiple servers. When one copy completes service, then the others are deleted. When a server becomes available it moves to the next compatible job. So I cannot just schedule a departure event when a job is taken into service as the service rate it gets can change over time. So I now schedule one arrival event for the entire system and poll which job departs based on the rates they get (job sizes are exponential). After an event I need to update these rates for the next departure event.

Comment: So part of this sounds like you should look into some of the algorithmic techniques used in kinetic Monte Carlo. The other part is that this seems like it's too big a problem to reasonably do in a language as slow as R.

Comment: Fair enough, I am very familiar with $R$ but over the years I have come to realize the limitations of it especially how slow it can be. Kinetic Monte Carlo is something I have never heard of, so I'll look into that. Thanks much for the input!

Comment: Kinetic Monte Carlo is a concept from the physics literature having to do with simulations of basically "classical atoms" undergoing various discrete transition events at state-dependent rates. The case that I am familiar with involves atoms on the surface of a crystal with surface defects. The methods for selecting an event to trigger, selecting a simulated time before it triggers, updating the state, and updating the rate table are very well optimized. You may find some inspiration by looking at their pseudocode.

Comment: Is the whole model Markov and time-homogeneous? Also, is the arrival rate for each type of job the same? It seems to me that if those are both true then it should not be as expensive as you're describing it to be with some reasonable optimizations.

Comment: In particular, if the arrival rates are the same then you can just generate a random subset of $\{ 1,2,\dots,N \}$ of size $d$ when an arrival event is triggered, rather than maintaining a structure mapping job types to compatible servers at all.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly how the arrivals are. Each job selects a subset of $d$ servers uniformly at random. The total arrival rate scales, such that it is $N \cdot \lambda$ in a model with $N$ servers. However I need to keep track which servers were selected, when the job is at the head of the queue of a server then this server works on the job in a processor sharing fashion.

Comment: OK, then you don't need a matrix like this at all. You can just generate a job, select $d$ servers for it uniformly at random, and then dispatch it to all the ones that are available. What's actually more difficult is dispatching a pending job to a server that has just finished a job; how are race conditions handled?

Comment: I'd like to try my hand at implementing a prototype of this myself to see what the computational difficulty is like, but I am somewhat unclear on how the dispatch operation works. Is it that you dispatch a job to each of the $d$ servers that it matches with, and then each of them adds it to their own FIFO queue, then the job is deleted from all $d$ of its servers whenever it is actually completed? Also, what is the typical ratio of arrival rate to server speed?

Comment: I made an attempt which seemed like it was about twice as fast in Matlab than you described but I was not correctly flushing jobs from other servers than the server that actually completed it. I need to put in a pivoting kind of data structure so that you select a server uniformly at random among the active servers, then fetch the job it was working on, then fetch all the servers that had that job in their queue to delete them.

Comment: So I am simulating a model with redundancy under cancel on completion. It is assumed we have job types, each type has a unique subset of servers that are compatible. Upon arrival a job is dispatched to all available servers. Whenever one redundant copy completes service, then all others are deleted. It can be assumed that the redundant copies have iid exponential job size requirement. The job/server compatibilities can be anything, hence why I made my simulating using the matrix.

Comment: I was now looking into the Red-d assignment policy, which assumes that for each subset of $d$ server there is a type. The arrival rate per type is assumed to be the same for all types. I have now rewritten my simulation such that I no longer use the matrix, but I just sample $d$ servers upon arrival and I now keep track of each of the queues of the servers (I originally tracked the state of the system via a central queue description). Each arriving job I give a unique identifier (the $i$-th arrival to the system will just have id $i$).

Comment: I now still generate one departure event for the whole system, but I sample for the server where a job departed based on their rate and the total rate of active servers (much easier to determine now, can just sum over the rates of servers of those that have nonzero queue length). I retrieve the identifier of the job at the head of the queue where the departure was and I remove that identifier from all the queues it's at. The simulation can still be optimised a lot, but for $N=250$ it brought down my running time from 3 hours to just 5 minutes for one iteration.

Comment: Yep, that was exactly what I had in mind. The key thing is that when enough things are uniform, you can strip out data structures involving them in favor of just counting how many of them exist.

Comment: Jup, thanks a lot for the valuable discussion! With this change I can get the numerical results much quicker than before (or I can run it for longer to get a better approximation).